# Extend a Json declaration

Tags: javascript, json

So I have this Json:

```
var json = 
{
    id : GetGUIDValue(),
    shockbps: bps,
    shockIncrements: incs
};
```

Another method gets called after this is set that passes in this Json:

```
function GetPrepayment(json)
```

However I have a boolean value that I want to include in the Json (that can't be included in the other methods that use this Json, only the current one). How do I add this boolean in the beginning of this method call so that every time this method gets called the boolean value is added in or changed if it's already there.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not JSON. You can't have a function call in JSON and property names must be quoted. That is a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: I believe that's not valid JSON, you need to enclose each in quotations as if they are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var some_obj = {
    id : GetGUIDValue(),
    shockbps: bps,
    shockIncrements: incs
};

function GetPrepayment( obj ) {
    obj.myBooleanProperty = true;

    // ...rest of the function code
}

GetPrepayment( some_obj );
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted already, that is not JSON but an Object Literal. Corresponding with the example you provided you can add properties as follows

```
json.property_name = property_value;
```